# I have finished the job vs I have the job finished

Tags: word-order

1. > He had a hot shower when he had **done** his exercises.
2. > He had a hot shower when he had his exercises **done**.

Which sounds strange?

Comment: It's not clear. Your title involves the present perfect and the question the past perfect, which one you want to ask?

Answer (score 1):

Both sound strange.

He should do one or the other first. Also repetition of the word "had" but with separate meanings is not advisable do to the confusion factor.

He took a shower after he had done his exercises.

As for where to place the "done", both are fine.

However the question title is not fine:

I have finished the job. This can only mean "I did it myself and it is completed".

I have the job finished...

could be followed by...

...by contractors.      I did/do not do it myself. It may or may not be completed depending on context

...before I leave every day.      I myself do it and it is continuous.

...and I can go home.          I myself did it and it is complete.

Those endings dont have to be present for the sentence to make sense but that then leaves it open to interpretation.